# How does React Context work by using a function inside of a component

Tags: reactjs

> How does this code work ? How can a function be called inside a
>   component?

```
import React from 'react'

const ThemeContext = React.createContext('blue');

const App = () =>
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={'green'}>
        <ThemeContext.Consumer>
            {(value) => <button style={{ background: value }}>Hello Context!</button>}
        </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>

export default App
```

I am trying to understand React Context internals , While it is clear how 
Context/Provider/Consumer can be used I just don't seem to understand how this line actually works calling a function inside of a component

```
<ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {(value) => <button style={{ background: value }}>Hello Context!</button>}
</ThemeContext.Consumer>
```

Is it possible have the same pattern work inside of a custom component? This throws a warning 'Functions are not valid as a React child.

```
<div>
{(value)=><span>{value}</span>}
</div>
```

Comment: Use hooks. It's 2020

Comment: I don't get an error for this code, https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-pond-x96sy

Comment: <div>
{(value)=><span>{value}</span>}
</div> //This shows a warning

Comment: The question is how does this code work ? by calling a function inside of a component what is the pattern used here it does not seem to be HOC either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**React Functions as Child Components**

So if I'm getting this right, you are basically asking how you could get a component which is in the following format:

```
<MyComponent>
  {(name) => (
    <div>{name}</div>
  )}
</MyComponent>
```

These are called functions as children. You do it by managing the state or a variable in a component locally and you pass that state or variable to any other component in the app by implementing *the children as a function* in `MyComponent`.

So your `MyComponent` component will look something as follows:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children('Scuba Steve')}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

This allows you to reuse `MyComponent` anywhere with the *exact same state or variables* **but you could render it differently**.

You would find this pattern quite a lot in libraries like [`react-final-form`](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) for example, where the library maintains a state and the users can "consume" that state and render it in anyway they want.

You can read more about it at [this link](https://medium.com/merrickchristensen/function-as-child-components-5f3920a9ace9) and at [this link as well](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/6/Using-Functions-as-Children-and-Render-Props-in-React-Components).

Comment: Thank you ! Got It https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-beaver-hq2u2

Comment: const Custom = (props) => <div>{props.children('Got It!')}</div>

Answer (score 2):

**Understand React Context internals**

The React Context Consumer children is a function instead of typical string or React Element

```
<ThemeContext.Consumer>
  {(value) => <button style={{ background: value }}>Hello Context!</button>}
</ThemeContext.Consumer>

<div>
  Hey, I'm normal JSX
</div>
```

The above code will be transpiled to

```js
React.createElement(ThemeContext.Consumer, null, function (value) {
    return React.createElement("button", {
      style: {
        background: value
      }
    }, "Hello Context!");
  })

React.createElement("div", null, "Hey, I'm normal JSX"))
```

You can see that the children (`props.children`) is a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
   {(value)=><span>{value}</span>}
</div>
```

This code is mean that you declared a function inside `<div>`. (Not calling that function any more)

```
<ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {(value) => <button style={{ background: value }}>Hello Context!</button>}
</ThemeContext.Consumer>
```

This function will be called inside `ThemeContext.Consumer` then your element will render

Comment: As mentioned https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-pond-x96sy this code actually works but how does it work ? by calling a function inside?

Comment: exactly! They call your function inside `ThemeContext.Consumer`. You can declare your component to replace their `Consumer` then calling your function as `props.children()` to test

Comment: Let us forget Context for now.Can this pattern be replicated with other class/functional components as well let us say <div>
   {(value)=><span>{value}</span>}
</div>

Comment: NO if you has outer `<div>`. You can declare your Component, then write down as below:

Comment: `<YourComponent> {(value)=><span></span>} </YourComponent>`

Comment: And don't forget to call `props.children()` in `render()` of `YourComponent`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-beaver-hq2u2 - This shows a warning as well

Comment: your code is incorrect! pls try this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sunset-zpmfc

Answer (score 0):

I see that it as more of a javascript question than a react specific; react components at the end the day will become a function; javascript support function as first-class, so a function can be passed to other function as arguments ( or returned as value ) hence the higher the components and context API. So your question can be roughly translated to this code snippet:

```js
function Theme (color) {
   /* some code maybe */
   return function Nav (TotalItems){
         return `I'll render a ${color} with ${TotalItems} TotalItems`;
   }
}

let redThemed = Theme( "dark red");
let navComp = redThemed(17);
console.log( navComp );
console.log( redThemed(12) );

let blueThemed = Theme( "light blue");
console.log( blueThemed(4) );
```